# Removing specific text from every line

Tags: python

I have a txt file with this format:

```
something text1 pm,bla1,bla1
something text2 pm,bla2,bla2
something text3 am,bla3,bla3
something text4 pm,bla4,bla4
```

and in a new file I want to hold:

```
bla1,bla1
bla2,bla2
bla3,bla3
bla4,bla4
```

I have this which holds the first 10 characters for example of every line. Can I transform this or any other idea?

```
with open('example1.txt', 'r') as input_handle:
    with open('example2.txt', 'w') as output_handle:
        for line in input_handle:
            output_handle.write(line[:10] + '\n')
```

Comment: In this situation you could just `.split(",")[1]`

Comment: Or with one line in awk. `awk -F, '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: `perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /.*,(.*)/' input > output`

Comment: Note that you will end up with an extra newline with this code.  Iteration over a file line by line keeps the original newline intact.

Comment: Sorry I made an update in the format of data maybe something for pm, and am, and after this remove the content?

Comment: I think you can do some really nice slicing in your case. (using numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the first ","-separated column from the file:

```
first, sep, rest = line.partition(",")
if rest: # don't write lines with less than 2 columns
   output_handle.write(rest)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module was made for.

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'))

for row in reader: print(row[1])
```

You can then just redirect the output of the file to the new file using your shell, or you can do something like this instead of the last line:

```
for row in reader:
    with open('out.csv','w+') as f:
        f.write(row[1]+'\n')
```

Comment: Why not use the `csv` module for the output as well?

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed:

```
with open('example1.txt', 'r') as input_handle:
    with open('example2.txt', 'w') as output_handle:
        for line in input_handle:
            if line:  # and maybe some other format check
                od = line.split(',', 1)
                output_handle.write(od[1] + "\n")
```

Comment: This doesn't include the commas from his intended output. You could add them back in, but why not just `line.split(',', 1)` and `write(od[1])`? Or use `partition`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would write it.

**Python 2.7**

```
import csv
with open('example1.txt', 'rb') as f_in, open('example2.txt', 'wb') as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)
    for row in csv.reader(f_in):
        writer.write(row[-2:]) # keeps the last two columns
```

**Python 3.x** (note the differences in arguments to `open`)

```
import csv
with open('example1.txt', 'r', newline='') as f_in:
    with open('example2.txt', 'w', newline='') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)
        for row in csv.reader(f_in):
           writer.write(row[-2:]) # keeps the last two columns
```

Comment: +1 for using `csv` for both input and output. (By the way, why explicitly specify 2.7? Is there anything here I'm missing that makes your code not work with 2.6, 3.x, etc.?)

Comment: @abarnert:  The first version puts two context managers on one line, which was introduced in 2.7.  I find it semi-distasteful to have to indent two levels just for safe file i/o.  However, I changed it to two lines in the 3.x version due to line length.

Comment: @abarnert: Also, in Python 2.x the csv module expects the file to opened in binary mode.  In Python 3.x, the csv module needs it in text mode and needs `newline=''`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
output_handle.write(line.split(",", 1)[1])
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> `str.split([`*sep*`[,` *maxsplit*`]])`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string, using *sep* as the delimiter string. If *maxsplit* is given, at most *maxsplit* splits are done (thus, the list will have at most `maxsplit+1` elements).